NPM package is not recognized by the CMD as a command
So created a simple npm package that can display my details. But when I run it using npx hiruja it shows a loading bar like thing and then says 'hiruja' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
It work on my iMac 12,1 running Catalina (The computer where I created it)
But it doesn't work on any other computer including Macs (So the os isn't the problem)
I checked the file structure and it is fine too.
Also tried npm pkg fix
I made sure I have the node.js upto date and also tested some packages with npx Please Help.
This is my code:
package.json
{
  "name": "hiruja",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "description": "Hiruja Edurapola",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "bin": {
    "hiruja": "index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "hiruja"
  ],
  "author": "Hiruja Edurapola",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "boxen": "^7.1.1",
    "chalk-animation": "^2.0.3"
  }
}

index.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

import boxen from 'boxen';
import chalkAnimation from 'chalk-animation';


let hiruja = `

    Name: Hiruja Edurapola
    Email: videohiruja@gmail.com
    `


const rainbow = chalkAnimation.rainbow(boxen(hiruja, {padding: 1})); 

The actual console.log have some more code including bunch of ascii art.
Here's how I published it.
chmod += index.js
npm link
npx hiruja //Tested locally
npm login
Then
npm publish
I don't have the log with with me but I remember that there was something like this:
WARN: npm autocoreccted some mistakes. run npm pkg fix to (something like that)

Can you share the command you used to publish this to NPM? It may be available in your history, depending how long it's been + frequency of terminal usage + exact history settings. Just be sure to sanitize any sensitive info.

I updated the question with how I published it. I was unable to find the history log.

Interesting. It doesn't look like it needs the field main as that's for packages that get required into other scripts whereas this is meant to be a binary that is installed. IDK if this would stop it from publishing, but it's worth a shot. If that fails, you could try adding a repository link. If you get any more errors, copy them and the commands used ASAP :P Lol. Also worth checking out changing your shell history settings, both for optimization and because it's kind of fun customizing the shell a bit.
